# Separate admin for each section in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a question: I have a table, for example, called "store". I want the main admin to define countless stores, and stores have a main admin who can define their own user. That user is defined according to the role of sand login. Can you help me? I tried a lot in this field, but I didn't succeed.

I also use ASP .NET Identity.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by "sand login"?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a main admin who can create stores and assign an admin for each store. The assigned admin creates users according to some role.

I won't tell you code wise how to do it, but if you want an idea, there are multiple approaches to this so I'll say 2 out of the top of my head.

You can create 3 tables for that. First one is Admin table with only one of them having a boolean called mainAdmin set to true.

Second table would be stores and it would have a foreign key for the admin it is assigned to.

Third table containing users and a foreign key of the user and one for which store it belongs to.

A second approach would be to make tables for the the roles. One for the responsibilities for each role and add them to a generic class called person.

Comment: thanks a lot 
Is it possible to use identity 3.1 in the second method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "identity 3.1".

Comment: I mean identity in asp.net core

Comment: Can you explain the second method?

Comment: I don't know what identity in asp.net core means. The second method is pretty much creating your roles, responsibilities and what should be viewed to whom as generic tables and assigning the values to any person you want to add.